# mysqli will connect but PDO fails SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'write_api'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Code is:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['password'], $db['database']);
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $db['host'] . ";dbname=" . $db['dbname'], $db['user'], $db['pass']);
```

The first line connects fine, the second line throws the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'write_api'
```

Settings are:

```
// DB settings
'db' => [
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => 'badpass',
    'dbname' => 'write_api',
]
```

I tried connecting directly to the socket,
`'socket' => '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',`, but this didn't help.

The database exists and I am using it:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| writer_api         |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can't figure out why everything but PDO can connect to it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you have a wrong dbname  in connection config  `'dbname' => 'write_api',`

but in your database you have `writer_api`

change

```
 'dbname' => 'writer_api'
```

Comment: You champion. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder

Comment: I'd ask people to not downvote this too. The more evidence that demonstrates that this problem is basically always human error, the better.

Comment: @Shammoo  don't worry .. is not a problem ..   .. thanks